# Simplifying null checks and equality

Tags: c#, null

I have two classes, `Person` and `Spouse`, and this method that checks for equality between spouses:

```
private bool SpousesSame(Person p1, Person p2)
{
    bool tempFlag = false;

    if (p1 != null && p2 != null && p1.Spouse != null && p2.Spouse != null && p1.Spouse == p2.Spouse)
    {
        tempFlag = true;
    }

    return tempFlag;
}
```

As you can see there are an awful lot of null checks (`Person` can be `null`, too).
Can this be simplified?

EDIT:
I'm trying to return `false` when both Persons are null as well.

Comment: @Fabio: That would also match if both are null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
private bool SpousesSame(Person p1, Person p2)
{
    return p1?.Spouse != null && p1.Spouse == p2?.Spouse;
}
```

`p1?.Spouse` will be null if either `p1` or `p1.Spouse` is null, in which case `false` will be returned.

Otherwise, we know that `p1.Spouse` is not null and can therefore compare it to `p2?.Spouse`.

Comment: Thanks very much for this response, but I'm getting a "Operator && cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'bool'" compiler error. Why is this?

Comment: Okay, my bad, I mistyped a `?` character somewhere in the code. It now works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the Elvis operator `?.` like so:

```
p1?.Spouse != null && p2?.Spouse != null
```

`p1?.Spouse` evaluates to `null` if `p1` is null, otherwise it evaluates to `p1.Spouse`. You can chain this together, so if there were another property on `Spouse` you could do something like:

```
p1?.Spouse?.Name
```

which would return the spouse's name but only if `p1.Spouse` and `p1` were both non-null to avoid null reference exceptions.

Further, I'd do your null-check in a separate if-block to your equality check, since the null-check is validation while the equality check is your actual logic. And unless there's more to your method you don't need to set `tempFlag`, you can just return a `bool` directly, so your method could be simplified to:

```
private bool SpousesSame(Person p1, Person p2)
{
    //return false if either person or their spouse is null
    if (p1?.Spouse == null || p2?.Spouse == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return (p1.Spouse == p2.Spouse);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your code with single assignment. This should be equivalent to your code also note that you don't need to check for properties since you've already checked for p1 and p2 parameters and have used the `&&` operator:

```
private bool SpousesSame(Person p1, Person p2)
{
     bool tempFlag = p1 != null && p2 != null && p1.Spouse == p2.Spouse;    
     return tempFlag;
}
```

Comment: The problem statement is "an awful lot of null checks", I think you can do more on that.